# Fragment's method from Activity Callback is not calling

Tags: android, android-fragments, fragment

I have done as below :

Implemented Listener in Activity as `MyCallBack.MyListener`

Initialized it in activity as below :

```
App.Manager.myCallback?.myListener(this)
```

Below is the method implemented :

```
override fun onGettingData(data: MyData) {

        var fragment1 = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container) as Fragment1
        if (fragment1 != null && fragment1.isVisible) {
            fragment1.onDataReceived(data)
        }

        var fragment2 = supportFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.container) as Fragment2
        if (fragment2 != null && fragment2.isVisible) {
            fragment2.onDataReceived(data)
        }
    }
```

But this method inside my fragments is not getting called.

Comment: Is `fragment1.onDataReceived(data)` and `fragment2.onDataReceived(data)` getting called?

Comment: Working for Fragment 1. not working for Fragment 2

Comment: Is that not what you were expecting? Surely the container only has one fragment at a time?

Comment: @HenryTwist Yes I am adding second fragment on fragment 1.

Answer (score 0):

Solution :

```
for (fragment in supportFragmentManager.fragments) {
        if (fragment is Fragment1) {
            fragment.onDataReceived(data)
        } else if (fragment is Fragment2) {
            fragment.onDataReceived(data)
        }
    }
```